# increments order in java

Tags: java, operator-precedence, evaluation, post-increment, jls

Why in java this code outputs 1:

```
int bracketsTest = 0;
int resultBrackets = 1 + bracketsTest + bracketsTest++; // return 1
```

But this outputs 2:

```
int bracketsTest = 0;
int resultBrackets = 1 + bracketsTest++ + bracketsTest; // return 2
```

I lived in the world where both snippets should be equal, since in both results we do the following:

1. 1 + 0 + bracketsTest // bracketsTest = 0 and we put zero in bracketsTest++, after that bracketsTest = 1
2. 1 + 0 + 1 = 2        // we put bracketsTest = 1 in last argument 
   but turns out that increment/decrement operation is not highest prioritet operations? (since it is matter where we put bracketsTest in code snippet)

Comment: The first one executes `1 + 0 + 0`. The last one executes `1 + 0 + 1` because the variable was incremented already before the last addend (`+ bracketsTest;`) is read. Im sure the JLS exactly specifies the order this snippet has to be executed somewhere (left to right in this case).

Comment: You seem to be mixing operator precedence and evaluation order? `++` has a higher precedence than `+`, but the evaluation order is always left to right in Java.

Comment: any ++ sign means that you increment the variable so if you use `++bracketsTest` that means that you will increment it and then use it and if you use `bracketsTest++` that will mean i will use it now with old value and then in any next usage I will use the incremented value. so in 2nd example you incremented it and used it after that so you will have the incremented value that is why 2nd example shows 2 and first shows 1

Comment: Evaluation order in the JLS: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Evaluation order

You seem to mix *operator precendence* with **evaluation order**. Please have a look at [JLS§15.7. Evaluation Order](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7):

> The Java programming language guarantees that the operands of operators appear to be evaluated in a specific evaluation order, namely, **from left to right**.

Also:

> The Java programming language guarantees that every operand of an operator (except the conditional operators &&, ||, and ? :) appears to be **fully evaluated** before any part of the **operation itself is performed**.

Additionally:

> The Java programming language respects the order of evaluation indicated explicitly by parentheses and **implicitly by operator precedence**.

But that part only plays a role once you perform the operation itself. Before that happens, all operands will already be fully evaluated.

---

### First snippet

Knowing that, we can decipher what is going on. The first snippet:

```
1 + bracketsTest + bracketsTest++
```

Will first of all evaluate all the operands (from left to right), so we get:

```
1. operand: 1
2. operand: 0
3. operand: 0 (and increment bracketsTest)
```

While evaluationg the third operand, it will increment `bracketsTest`. Now, it will add everything together and we get `1 + 0 + 0 = 1` as result.

---

### Second snippet

The second snippet:

```
1 + bracketsTest++ + bracketsTest;
```

is evaluated from left to right as well, so we have:

```
1. operand: 1
2. operand: 0 (and increment bracketsTest)
3. operand: 1 (because it was just incremented)
```

Hence we receive `1 + 0 + 1 = 2`.

Comment: Yeah, now I understand, thanks a lot! Indeex I mixed operator precendence and evaluation order

Answer (score 1):

The second addition expression is evaluated left to right, as:

```
int resultBrackets = 1 + bracketsTest++ + bracketsTest;

1               (add 1)
bracketsTest++  (add zero, then increment bracketsTest by 1)
bracketsTest    (add 1, the current value of bracketsTest)
```

The sum therefore evaluates to 2.

Comment: After reading OPs question again, I think he already knows that but is rather asking why the order is like that and where (in the JLS) this is written down and explained. Could be wrong though.

Comment: ...and I have explained step by step how we arrive at sum of 2.